# How to deep copy a dictionary without .deepcopy

Tags: python, dictionary, jython-2.5

Is there a way to create a deep copy of a dictionary without the [copy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) module?  I need to copy a dictionary of dictionaries N times, but am working in an environment with pared down Jython libraries that do not include [copy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html).  I cannot add modules to this system.

I could convert the dictionaries to lists and use [:] to copy, but was wondering if it is possible with dictionaries.

Comment: What kinds of values are in the dictionaries (besides other dictionaries)?

Answer (score 0):

So the dictionary-inside-dictionary goes only one level deep? If so, you could try:

```
copy = {}
for k, v in original.items():
    copy[k] = dict(v)
```